# Turning the desert green with invasive plants

Tags: flora, deserts

I don't like the sand, but apparently deserts are inevitable since I don't remember reading about a period on earth when there were no deserts.

So I was thinking, what invasive plants of earth has the potential to turn a dry and hot desert into something greener? or do I have to invent some mega-super-duper-uber-pflanze like the ''handwavia Fabacea'' ?

But we have stuff already growing on vulcanoes or antartica so I probably there must be something that can colonize deserts like the sahara that just didn't have a chance to occur yet.

Comment: The desert is there because lack of water, either atmospheric or terrain-based issues deprive a region of water, and there you go, a desert. You would probably need cactuses like those in US's dry regions that would be able to absorb and preserve water inside themselves in order to help other life survive nearby, but if you just don't have a source of water, ANYWHERE, nothing could help.

Comment: It's off-topic to what you directly ask, but I think there are other ways to counter-act deserts : Humidity, soil saltiness and acidity, temperature and sunlight cycles... By the way, don't forget frozen deserts :).

Comment: Yes, there is something which can colonize the Sahara: the Touaregs. They are not vegetable, though. (And the question would greatly benefit from a picture of the lush greenery recently discovered in Antarctica and never yet shown on the internet.) (Seriously, a desert is desertic because there is no water there. It there is some form of water available, then ingenious plants like [*Welwitschia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welwitschia) will make use of it; but it there is none, there is none.)

Comment: -1 for lack of research. Had humanity an answer to this question as asked, we would have implemented it thousands of years ago. You are expected to do your due diligence before asking questions. You've not researched why deserts are the way they are - and it's a LOT more complicated than lack of water. Utah's Strawberry Reservoir is surrounded by what is almost a desert (sparse sage brush). Lack of water isn't the problem. Lack of soil/compost, supporting bacteria, and the supporting insects and animals to sustain greater plant growth are all involved.

Comment: And I'd like to make one more comment. Over the last few years there has been a growing tendency to ask for help developing a completely fantastic condition *as if it could really exist.* (See [this Meta question expressing frustration over the issue](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10029/40609)). Per the [help/on-topic], we're here to help you build an *imaginary world.* Let's stick to that context. What's stopping you from setting a rule that you have a desert-condition plant that's prolific?

Comment: @JBH because I'd prefer if there was already something real to use......there's thousands of questions asking about real things in this website. The question arises because I've seen some documentaries on people using invasive plants to fertilize frozen of iceland deserts or the arid cold deserts of northern china/russia but I have found nothing on hot-dry deserts

Comment: @JBH sounds like some stupid logic ''if there was something we would have already solved the problem''..... no it doesn't work like that sometimes the solution is in front of your nose but can't be used or won't be used either because of politics, environmentalists moralists or because people just didn't notice it.

Comment: @JBH and what more research do I need to do? I've gotta read every book on botany out there, or maybe... but just maybe there's a more efficient way to this... like asking to see if someone with botanic culture has already studied something like this

Comment: As irritated as you may be, bear in mind that it's your responsibility to follow the site's rules, not our responsibility to answer every question put to us. No, you don't need to read every book, but you are expected to do some research. In fact, the [help] even suggests that it's helpful to explain why your research failed to answer the question. And there's a big difference between "realistic" and "real life." Too many questions are seeking a Real Life solution rather than a Real Life example that could be used as a template for a fantastic solution.

Comment: BTW, if you insist on only Real Life solutions, you'll find better answers on [biology.se] or [earthscience.se]. I really mean it when I say our focus is imaginary worlds. We permit Real World questions in a worldbuilding context, but maybe it's time to start redirecting people who only want Real World answers to the Stacks that exist for those answers.

Comment: Nice Try Muad'dib - stop trying to fulfil the prophecy and make a paradise of Arrakis.

Comment: Note that getting rid of deserts would lower planetary albedo, which would run the risk of raising world temperatures.

Comment: volcanoes and Antarctica have water. the only way to green a desert is by adding water, which is possible with engineering but not just botany.

Comment: @GrandmasterB maybe, it could also lower it by increasing cloud cover. Albedo is hard to predict.

Comment: Check out https://pubs.usgs.gov/gip/deserts/types/ as to why deserts exist. Before looking to plants, see why the earth has desert at that location.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is a bit confused. Let's look at the different parts:

> I don't like the sand, but apparently deserts are inevitable since I don't remember reading about a period on earth when there were no deserts.

OK, Earth has always had sand deserts. I'll take your word for it but I guess it isn't implausible.

> So I was thinking, what invasive plants of earth has the potential to turn a dry and hot desert into something greener?

If one did, why would there still be deserts on Earth ? Why would there always have been sand deserts on Earth ? That's the thing about life - it tends to go everywhere it can, especially given geological timescales to work with.

> But we have stuff already growing on vulcanoes or antartica so I probably there must be something that can colonize deserts like the sahara that just didn't have a chance to occur yet.

I mean, there are stuff growing on volcanoes and Antarctica yet Antarctica has *very few* stuff growing in it. I'm less sure why you're highlighting volcanoes as being inhospitable, when they're not erupting they're a mountain like any other and pretty fertile as those go actually IIRC, and when they're erupting, well... I don't know of any stuff that grows in liquid lava. Either way, there's also stuff growing in the Sahara. The issue is *there's not a lot of it*, but that's also true of Antarctica.

But either way the same issue arises as with the previous sentence - if such a thing existed it would have greened the Sahara already, would it not? So logically it probably doesn't exist in our current world, right?

> or do I have to invent some mega-super-duper-uber-pflanze like the ''handwavia Fabacea'' ?

That seems like the obvious conclusion and I'm not sure what other answer you're expecting. Are you asking for general principles of plant life to help you construct a plausible ''handwavia Fabacea'' ? Or do you think there is an actual plant species out there that *could* green all deserts but didn't for lack of opportunity, and somebody on this forum knows about this plant, knows it *could* green all deserts but hasn't done anything to spread this knowledge or act on it ? (not saying they *should* act on it if they knew, just that humans being what they are it seems pretty surprising they wouldn't at least have tried something, or talked about it. More to the point even *acquiring the knowledge* that a plant could, but didn't, green the Sahara would IRL require experimenting with actually making the plant do that)

Answer (score 1):

Everybody who has ever studied permaculture has learned [Bill Mollison's answer](https://permies.com/t/55179/Mollisons-Desert-Garden-Plant-Assembly) that American deserts have cacti, African deserts have bulbs, Australian deserts have seed-foods, and by combining them in one desert, you could get a high food-yield.

The Kalahari has 16 nice berries, but the best food is below the ground. [The Marama bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tylosema_esculentum) is an important desert food in the Kalahari. You've got the marotse melon, you've got over 400 cultivated cacti in America, including dragonfruit and prickly pear. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKIgqa49rMc) is a wonderful 2000-year-old food forest planted and grown Morocco. It has: date palms, olives, figs, guava, citrus, mulberry, tamarind, carib, pomegranate, banana, quince, grape.

The key to turning the desert green is reducing evaporation. (Others have commented that deserts are there because there's no water whatsoever. This is wrong. There's water in all places. There's precipitation in all places except for the Atacama, and that's foggy.)

There are lots of desert trees from different continents, and by assembling them, you start to trap moisture. I remember once seeing a list of TEN ways in which trees improve moisture. I don't remember them all, but some are: the humus they put in the ground improves the water retention, orographic effects create rain, shade reduces evaporation, leaves act as a surface for condensation, etc.

You didn't specify which desert you are talking about – growing conditions in Australia are very different from in the Lut Desert.

Taking the Sahara as one example, there are [over 1.8 billion trees in an area of 1.3 million km²](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2824-5). The study notes "The canopy cover increases from 0.1% (0.7 trees per hectare) in hyper-arid areas, through 1.6% (9.9 trees per hectare) in arid and 5.6% (30.1 trees per hectare) in semi-arid zones, to 13.3% (47 trees per hectare) in sub-humid areas", with the definitions "hyper-arid (rainfall of 0–150 mm yr−1), arid (rainfall of 150–300 mm yr−1), semi-arid (rainfall of 300–600 mm yr−1) to sub-humid (rainfall of 600–1,000 mm yr−1) areas. Britannica says of the Sahara, "[Although precipitation is highly variable, it averages about 3 inches (76 millimetres) per year.](https://www.britannica.com/place/Sahara-desert-Africa/Climate)", so the majority of it you could expect 0.7 trees per hectare to already be there naturally, and you'd likely have good luck growing more, especially if you use the best techniques like clay pots buried near the sapling, mulch, etc.

Point is there are trees in deserts, as anyone who has been in deserts knows. Deserts are just places where precipitation is low and evaporation is high. The best way to reduce evaporation is trees. You can assemble desert trees from different continents: Africa's Ricinodendron rautanenii (Manketti or mongongo), the [Quandong tree from Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santalum_acuminatum), various acacias, various cypresses, the Mesquite tree which grows in salt pans and provides forage for bees as well as herbivores. A lot depends on the specifics of your desert (salinity, alkalinity, precipitation, other xericulture techniques like earthworks), but your question specified plants and these are the ones you want.

Comment: Sure there is *some* precipitation in the Sahara. About 100 to 150 mm (4 to 6 in) per year. Good luck growing a tree with that. As for the mysterious Mr. Mollison, do you have a link to a description of the wonderful gardens he planted and grew in the great Saharan hamadas? Oh wait, he didn't.

Comment: The trouble isn't growing a tree with it... it's growing anything at all such that the sand will stop duning up, soil can be built for the next 10,000 years and trap enough moisture that you can bootstrap up to better plants. The word "desert" might not be the best one, @AlexP, but there is a problem with soil erosion in these places that makes them even more inhospitable than they'd be given their rainfall. Organisms alter their own environment to better suit themselves, unless the environment falls into a trap so extreme none can wedge in a toehold.

Comment: Exactly John O, bootstrapping is the word. More trees mean more moisture which makes it easier to grow even more trees. We don't know what conditions the world in the question is working with. With enough labour, organisation, etc. it's certainly possible. With a runaway massive invasion of acacias, cypreses, quandongs, and mesquites??? A little more questionable but I'd say acceptably plausible for fiction.

Comment: To develop the 'bootstrapping' idea: this means geographical bootstrapping too. The semi-arid ridges (equivalent of the Sahel) could be tree'd up more easily. This would make the desert shrink; what was deeper desert is now the new semi-arid fringe. Plant that up. Repeat. Green marches mile by mile into yellow.

Comment: @wokopa more trees can actually mean less moisture, plants need to respire meaning they take water out of the ground and put it in the air where it is both easier to evaporate but also easier to simply blow away. this is why agriculture can often make deserts expand.  And you would need to reduce evaporation to an impossible extent in many deserts, just the air temp is enough for high evaporation. greening deserts have been successfully done, by using desalination, AKA adding more water, evaporation stays the same.

Comment: @John there seem to be plants specialized to live in arid regions, that don't expend water into the air as hard as agricultural species do. They also have a better use of fog and precipitation when it comes, thus initially planting agave and cacti could work, then trees of the same kind could also start to grow by the virtue of raising local water levels and/or lowering ambient temperature.